# Material-UI: How to get the value in Slider?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, slider

I'm using Material-UI [Slider](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#discrete-sliders) and I want to get the value with `onChange` function.

My code is like this:

```
const SliderScale: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(0);

  const updateRange = (value: number) : void => {
    setInputValue(value);
  };


  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography id="discrete-slider" gutterBottom>
        value
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        defaultValue={0}
        value={inputValue}
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
        step={0.5}
        marks={false}
        min={0}
        max={10}
        onChange={updateRange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SliderScale;
```

this doesn't work and show this error.

> (JSX attribute) onChange?: ((event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, value: number | number[]) => void) | undefined
> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType; } & { 'aria-label'?: string | undefined; 'aria-labelledby'?: string | undefined; 'aria-valuetext'?: string | undefined; color?: "primary" | "secondary" | undefined; ... 18 more ...; valueLabelFormat?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
> Type '(value: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent<{}>, value: number | number[]) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'event' are incompatible.
> Type 'ChangeEvent<{}>' is not assignable to type 'number'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<SliderTypeMap<{}, "span">>): Element', gave the following error.

Does anyone know how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onChange` signature from the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/slider) is:

> `function(event: object, value: number | number[]) => void`

The new value is in the second parameter, not the first one of `onChange` callback. Change your code to this:

```
<Slider {...props} onChange={(_, value) => setInputValue(value)} />
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed it but still not work. this error show on value  this time. 
＞ (parameter) value: number | number[]
Argument of type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'.
  Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<number>'.
    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: @knkn cast the value to number because it can either be a `number` or an array of `number`: `onChange={(_, value) => setInputValue(value as number)}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `updateRange` function to something like this:

```
const updateRange  = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number | number[]) => {
    setInputValue(newValue as number[]);
}
```